# Left and right slide out menu with slideout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using slideout.js to create my hamburger menus. I have created the left menu, but I cannot find out how to create the right one.

The code I'm using for the left one is:

```
var slideout = new Slideout({
    'panel': document.getElementById('panel'),
    'menu': document.getElementById('menu'),
    'padding': 256,
    'tolerance': 70
});
document.querySelector('.js-slideout-toggle').addEventListener('click', function () {
    slideout.toggle();
});
```

And the only difference to the right one will be adding `'side': 'right'`

In the API it says you can use `slideout.destroy();` Cleans up the instance so another slideout can be created on the same area. But I'm not sure how to implement this in the new code.

For the right slideout I did this:

```
var slideout = new Slideout({
    'panel': document.getElementById('panel'),
    'menu': document.getElementById('shop'),
    'padding': 256,
    'tolerance': 70,
    'side': 'right'
});
document.querySelector('.js-slideout-toggle-right').addEventListener('click', function () {
    slideout.toggle();
});
```

But this doesn't work. Once I click on the .js-slideout-toggle-right button, it doesn't open on the right. Once I click on the .js-slideout-toggle to open the left menu, the right one opens and the left one does not open. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm quite confused of what you're trying to achieve. Is firing the destroy method alone and create the new slideout instance didn't fix your problem? how far have you tried?

Comment: Well, you just add  'side': 'right' and then follow the same process as for left. What exactly you want to do, can you share a snippet of your code?

Comment: @Roljhon 

This is what I did with new id's.

`var slideout = new Slideout({
    'panel': document.getElementById('panel'),
    'menu': document.getElementById('shop'),
    'padding': 256,
    'tolerance': 70,
    'side': 'right'
});
document.querySelector('.js-slideout-toggle-right').addEventListener('click', function () {
    slideout.toggle();
});`

Comment: @DennisNovac Thanks Dennis! I have updated my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had only one variable, when you need two, so it messed up a little.

You just have to specify if it's `slideoutRight` or `slideoutLeft`, here you go:

```
var slideoutLeft = new Slideout({
    'panel': document.getElementById('panel'),
    'menu': document.getElementById('menu'),
    'padding': 256,
    'tolerance': 70
});
document.querySelector('.js-slideout-toggle').addEventListener('click', function () {
    slideoutLeft.toggle();
});


var slideoutRight = new Slideout({
    'panel': document.getElementById('panel'),
    'menu': document.getElementById('shop'),
    'padding': 256,
    'tolerance': 70,
    'side': 'right'
});
document.querySelector('.js-slideout-toggle-right').addEventListener('click', function () {
    slideoutRight.toggle();
});
```

Comment: Oh, didn't think of that. Works perfectly!